# SilverStripe edit gridfield success message on save

Tags: silverstripe

What's the easiest way to edit the default success message when saving an item in GridField edit view?

The message seems to be in a variable in class `GridFieldDetailForm` within method `doSave`.

```
$message = _t(
        'GridFieldDetailForm.Saved',
        'Saved {name} {link}',
        array(
            'name' => $this->record->i18n_singular_name(),
            'link' => $link
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the message uses the `_t()` function it will attempt to fetch the value defined in the lang file corresponding to the current user's locale. The default string defined in the function is just a fallback for when no translation could be found within the lang files.

To change the message you can update your site's yml lang file located in `mysite/lang/{LANGUAGE_CODE}.yml`

For english this would be:

```yml
# mysite/lang/en.yml
# remember to flush after editing me :-)
en:
  GridFieldDetailForm:
    Saved: 'My custom message using {name} and here is a link to the object: {link}'
```

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/

Comment: Cheers Janne, but I need to change the actual message to include for example new variables rather than {name} and {link}, it is in this case necessary to change more than just the translation.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for specific implementations

```
$form = $gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldDetailForm');
$form->setItemEditFormCallback(function($form, $itemRequest)
{
    // Replace save action with custom method in here
});
```

For more general implementations, you'll likely want to extend `GridFieldDetailForm` and override doSave, then replace the `GridFieldDetailForm` component with your custom class.